# pyparsing not parsing the whole string

Tags: pyparsing

I have the following grammar and test case:

```
from pyparsing import Word, nums, Forward, Suppress, OneOrMore, Group

#A grammar for a simple class of regular expressions
number = Word(nums)('number')
lparen = Suppress('(')
rparen = Suppress(')')

expression = Forward()('expression')

concatenation = Group(expression + expression)
concatenation.setResultsName('concatenation')

disjunction = Group(lparen + OneOrMore(expression + Suppress('|')) + expression + rparen)
disjunction.setResultsName('disjunction')

kleene = Group(lparen + expression + rparen + '*')
kleene.setResultsName('kleene')

expression << (number | disjunction | kleene | concatenation)

#Test a simple input
tests = """
(8)*((3|2)|2)
""".splitlines()[1:]

for t in tests:
    print t
    print expression.parseString(t)
    print
```

The result should be

```
[['8', '*'],[['3', '2'], '2']]
```

but instead, I only get

```
[['8', '*']]
```

How do I get pyparsing to parse the whole string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `concatenation` expression is not doing what you want, and comes close to being left-recursive (fortunately it is the last term in your expression). Your grammar works if you instead do:

```
expression << OneOrMore(number | disjunction | kleene)
```

With this change, I get this result:

```
[['8', '*'], [['3', '2'], '2']]
```

EDIT:
You an also avoid the precedence of `<<` over `|` if you use the `<<=` operator instead:

```
expression <<= OneOrMore(number | disjunction | kleene)
```

Comment: Thanks! Why does this work when just writing out the definition for concatenation doesnt, though?

Comment: Because your original expression matches a `kleene`, and nothing in your original `expression` definition says to keep parsing afterward. When you had `concatenation` included as part of `expression`, that would have conveyed that idea, but would have taken you down the left-recursion rabbit hole. Or if you replaced your `|` operators with `^` operators (to give a "match-longest" Or expression instead of MatchFirst), then you would get concatenation evaluation also - but again, you would then left-recurse by trying to evaluate an `expression` by evaluating an `expression`.

Comment: What version of pyparsing are you using? Current versions include some helpful methods, especially `expression.runTests`, which will take a multiline string of test inputs and run your expression against each line and printing the parsed results or diagnostic output. In your example, you could replace your for loop at the end with just `expression.runTests(tests)`. The truth is, over the years I have written that exact same for loop about a thousand times, and it finally dawned on me that a helper method on expressions would be of use.

Answer (score 6):

`parseString` has a parameter `parseAll`. If you call `parseString` with `parseAll=True` you will get error messages if your grammar does not parse the whole string. Go from there!